# ¿Cómo evitar que se desordenen los campos de la estructura de un array al persistirlos?

Tags: array, mongodb, update, push

Definidos:

```
type paidticket struct {
TipoDoc    string    `bson:"tipodoc"`
FechaDoc   time.Time `bson:"fechadoc"`
Sucursal   int       `bson:"sucursal"`
NumCaja    int       `bson:"numcaja"`
NumCom     int       `bson:"numcom"`
LetraIva   string    `bson:"letraiva"`
Monto      float32   `bson:"importe"`
Moneda     string    `bson:"moneda"`
FormaPago  string    `bson:"formapago"`
TipoCambio float32   `bson:"tipocambio"`
```

}

type item struct {
Cliente  string       `bson:"_id"`
Nombre   string       `bson:"nombre"`
Tickets  []paidticket `bson:"pagos"`
Recibido time.Time    `bson:"recibido"`
}

Luego del UpdateOne() con el operador $push todas las claves de los elementos quedan desordenadas.( Debajo deberín verse en este orden: tipodoc, fechadoc, sucursal, numcaja, numcom, letraiva, importe, moneda, formapago, tipocambio)

Persistidos pero desordenadas las claves:

```
{ 
"_id" : "21300996", 
"pagos" : [
    {
        "numcom" : NumberInt(2982), 
        "importe" : 13600.0, 
        "tipocambio" : 1.0, 
        "fechadoc" : ISODate("2022-05-02T07:30:00.000+0000"), 
        "sucursal" : NumberInt(52), 
        "letraiva" : "B", 
        "moneda" : "ARS", 
        "formapago" : "EF", 
        "tipodoc" : "FC", 
        "numcaja" : NumberInt(3)
    }, 
    {
        "fechadoc" : ISODate("2022-05-10T09:30:00.000+0000"), 
        "sucursal" : NumberInt(52), 
        "numcom" : NumberInt(2990), 
        "importe" : 6500.0, 
        "tipocambio" : 1.0, 
        "tipodoc" : "FC", 
        "numcaja" : NumberInt(3), 
        "letraiva" : "B", 
        "moneda" : "USD", 
        "formapago" : "EF"
    }
], 
"recibido" : ISODate("2022-05-24T15:03:42.165+0000")
```

}

Comment: como estás haciendo el push?

Comment: @Pipe gracias por responder. La sentencia con el $push es la siguiente:
  addPago := bson.M{"$push": bson.M{"pagos": data}}

  ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*5)

  _, err := col.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, &addPago, &opt)